# start /wait /d - not working on window 10 and windows 2019 server

Tags: windows

I am trying to create script that launches notpad.exe, waits till it closes, then runs one final command. Based on my research, I want to use the "/WAIT" flag but it doesn't seem to work :'(. Im on Windows 10 x64 fully updated.

Here is the script:

```
echo Welcome to notepad
start  /B /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
echo "hello notepad"
```

Note: this code working in window7 OS.

please let me if any idea/solution is there.

Comment: Hi All, Here "notepad" code is just an example which is having similar issue to my application issue. actually i am starting some other DB service. Here my intention is next line should not execute until the service is started. hence i used "/Wait" command.echo Welcome to DB service
start /B /WAIT "" "C:\launchDBservice.exe" -config "d:\\test.txt"
echo "hello notepad"

Comment: This works fine for me on Win10 Pro/1709, though the `/b` has no relevance for a GUI application. What may be happening is that your launch service is completing before the service is started, as is the case with `sc start`. The only way I know to make sure that a started service is running is to loop checking `sc query ServiceName` for the state `RUNNING`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use start, it should wait until the program is closed.

Your script would look like this:

```
echo Welcome to notepad
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
echo "hello notepad"
```

Start is useful to make explorer handle the request, but in your case that isn't necessary. Start can be useful to launch the program responsible for certain extensions. For example, to start Word and open your docx file: you would use

```
start "" c:\files\file.docx
```

start can also be used to start multiple programs at the same time without waiting for each other.

Keep in mind, Notepad++ only allows one instance to be opened. If you start notepad++ a second time, that process is killed instantly, so the script continues.

Comment: `Start` command used by OP works with `Notepad.exe` but not with `Notepad++`. Don't understand why. `start  /B /WAIT "" "notepad.exe"` waits till notepad is closed.

Comment: This doesn't work with i.e. the `UWP app calc.exe` which spawns another exe and immediatley returns.

Comment: @LotPings it will launch calc, but it will not wait. This is something in the design of apps and can't be dealed with unless you go through a lot of hasstle to program a waiting routine.

Comment: @Sandeep ah good point. This must be related to notepad++ only allowing one instance to be run. If an instance is opened, the process spawned will activate the other instance then the process itself closes. So the script continues since that instance no longer runs.